# как в PHP прибавить к DAYTIME еще 2 часа

Tags: php

помогите написать вот такой пример, пользователю дается 2 дня на выполнение работы, они должен видеть когда время закончилось.

беру из Базы данных параметр date, это дата начало работы, у которого тип DAYTIME

```
$Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `date` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1"));


новое_время = $Row[date] + 2 дня;

if (новое_время > время_сейчас)) {echo 'время закончилось';}
else {echo 'время еще есть';}
```

Comment: Ну так и берите из базы +2 дня: `SELECT date+interval 2 day FROM table WHERE id = 1`

Comment: Или даже так: `SELECT if(date+interval 2 day>now(),1,0) FROM table WHERE id = 1` Он вам вернет 1 если дата+2 дня больше текущей или 0 в противном случае

Comment: не срабатывает когда потом  через echo вывожу $Row[date] ни чего не пишет

Comment: Да, колонка перестает называться date, надо брать по номеру или присваивать имя с помощью `as`, написал в ответе варианты ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берите прямо из базы +2 дня:

```
SELECT `date`+interval 2 day as date2 FROM table WHERE id = 1
используем $Row[date2]
```

Или сразу получаем признак:

```
$Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT if(`date`+interval 2 day>now(),'закончилось','еще есть') as msg FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1"));
echo 'Время '.$Row['msg'];
```

Обратите внимание, в обоих случаях вычисляемой колонке присваиваем имя по которому мы потом увидим его в нашем массиве, с помощью `as имя`

Comment: работает, большое спасибо вам за помощь